# jQuery getting the this child value

Tags: jquery, children

My question is pretty straight forward.

The code below logs "this" properly, and prints out the desired child element:

```
console.log( $(this).children()[0] );
```

Prints:

```
<span>test result</span>
```

Trying to retrieve its value throws an exception. I'm using:

```
$((this).children()[0]).val()
```

Which throws:

```
Property 'children' of object [object HTMLAnchorElement] is not a function
```

What is wrong with my syntax ?

HTML:

```
<li>
<a href="#">
<span>example 1</span>
<span>example 1 sibling</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">
<span>example</span> 
<span>example 2 sibling</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">
<span>example</span> 
<span>example 3 sibling</span>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#">
<span>example</span>
<span>example 4 sibling</span></a>
</li>
```

Comment: you simply made a typo. `(this)` evaluates to a regular AnchorElement instead of the jQueryElement you expected. You need `$(this)`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please post it as such and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo. `(this)` evaluates to a htmlAnchorElement, and not a jQueryElement. Therefore it doesn't have a method `.children()`. It should be `$(this)`.

Answer (score 6):

since the child is a span you need to get `text()` or `html()` not `val()`.

```
$(this).children().eq(0).text()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UYmMy/)

Comment: It doesn't have any children

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `$(this).children()[0] ` is the `span`. so `this` is the parent element not the `span`

Comment: The code you provided returns the value of the both span elements. (Yes there are only two). According to what you say only the value of the first span found should be returned.

Comment: That is not what I get. I'm getting both values. joined. I'm adding my html structure.

Comment: @elad.chen please share your html and what `this` refers to in your context

Comment: @elad.chen also if you can edit the fiddle I added above to fit your case

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks for trying. The comment on my question itself was the correct one :). I missed a $ sign

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you're getting the selected jQuery object, turning it into a native element, then back into a jQuery object and trying to get it's value, when `span` element do not have a value. Also, the `span` in your example does not have any child elements, so using `children()` is redundant. Try this instead:

```
var spanText = $(this).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML  element is an inline element that can be used as a container for text.

V/s

The HTML  element is a block level element that can be used as a container for grouping other HTML elements.

So try

```
$(this).children().text()
```